# Does a view function use gas if called by another function which access the same storage variable?

Tags: solidity, gas, storage

Let's say I have a `view` function that accesses a `storage` mapping like so:

```
function performCalculation(uint256 _id) public view returns(uint256) {
      uint256 memory someValue = someMapping[_id];
      return someValue - 10;
}
```

And I have another function which also accesses that same value:

```
function someFunction(uint256 _id) external {
      uint256 storage someValue = someMapping[_id];
      // do something
}
```

If inside `someFunction` I needed to perform the same calculation that `performCalculation` does, would calling `performCalculation` from `someFunction` use more gas as it is accessing storage again? Would the better solution be to just do the same calculation inline using the `someValue` from `someFunction`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `someFunction` in a transaction, it would cost either more or the same gas.

The fact that it's a `view` function only allows calling this using a node RPC instead of submitting a transaction, but it doesn't reduce the cost of a mined transaction.

Comment: Does this apply if `someFunction` was called externally, which would then mean `performCalculation` was called internally by `someFunction`?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, fixed my answer accordingly.